# c++ initialize 2d array of pointers with null?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

```
class A {
   private:
      B* my2DArray[max1][max2];
};
```

How to initialize my2DArray with NULL here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define your own constructor that value initializes the array, setting all of its elements to null pointers. That's done by providing `()` initializer for the member, which also works for arrays.

```
class A
{
public:
  A():my2DArray() { }
private:
  B* my2DArray[max1][max2];
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use memset:

```
memset(&my2DArray, 0, max1*max2*sizeof(B*));
```